# Set value to var with trap

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have task in my university

Could you help me?

I need to change the method of using trap
and add or multiply using tail -n 0 -f

my code of generator:

```
rm info.txt
touch info.txt && chmod u+x info.txt

while true;
do
    read line
    case $line in
    "quit")
        echo $line >> info.txt
        exit
    ;;
    "+")
        kill -USR1 $(cat .pid)
    ;;
    "*")
        kill -USR2 $(cat .pid)
    ;;
    *)
        echo $line >> info.txt
    ;;
    esac
done
```

my code of hundler:

```
echo $$ > .pid

ME="+";
value=1;

multipl(){
    ME="*"
}
plus(){
    ME="+"
}

trap 'multipl' USR1
trap 'plus' USR2

(tail -n 0 -f info.txt) | while true
do
    read line
    case $line in
    "quit")
        echo "quit"
        killall tail
        exit
    ;;
    *)
        if (echo "$line" | grep -Eq "^-?[0-9]+$")
        then
            if [[ "$ME" == "+" ]]
            then
                let value=$value+$line
            fi
            if [[ "$ME" == "*" ]]
            then
                let value=$value*$line
            fi
            echo $value
        else
            echo "error"
            killall tail
            exit
        fi
    esac

    sleep 1
done
```

but my multipl(){ ME="*" } don't work

do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: It is possible that the star (`*`) charater will be expanded. Check your simple/double quote. And use `set -x` to see what's happened when running your script.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
let value=$value*$line
```

Because it is unquoted, the `*` will be expanded into the list of files in the current directory -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

You want this

```
let "value=$value*$line"
```

or use bash-specific arithmetic syntax

```
(( value *= line ))
```

---

"Doesn't work" is utterly useless as a problem report.

Are you quoting "$ME"? Consider this:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
$ multipl(){
   ME="*"
}
$ multipl
$ echo "$ME"
*
$ echo $ME
file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: my functions: multipl(){
    ME="*"
}
plus(){
    ME="+"
} doesn't work, other work...